# How can I check if the AWS SDK was provided with credentials?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

There are [many ways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html) to provide the AWS SDK with credentials to perform operations.

I want to make sure *any* of the methods were successful in setting up the interface before I try my operation on our continuous deployment system.

How can I check if AWS SDK was able to find credentials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access them via the [`config.credentials` property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#credentials-property) on the main client. All AWS service libraries included in the SDK have a [config property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html).

> **Class: AWS.Config**
>
> The main configuration class used by all service objects to set the region, credentials, and other options for requests.
>
> By default, credentials and region settings are left unconfigured. This should be configured by the application before using any AWS service APIs.

```
// Using S3
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
console.log(s3.config.credentials);
```

Comment: FYI, it works with any other v2 api too. E.g. `const sqs = new AWS.SQS()` and then `sqs.config.credentials`